# How to mute the spark dataframe error exception

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark-sql

When joining two dataframes, I get this extremely verbose error which shows the whole history of operations made to that dataframe along with my error. For example:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val namesAge = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("Sohum", "Sachdev", 24), Row("Jack", "Bauer", "53")))

val df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(namesAge, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("name", StringType),
  StructField("surname", StringType),
  StructField("age", IntegerType))
)).filter($"name" =!= "Sam").as('a) //dummy operations for example sake

val namesColor = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(Row("Sohum", "Sachdev", "black"), Row("Jack", "Bauer", "blue")))
val df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(namesColor, StructType(Seq(
  StructField("first_name", StringType),
  StructField("surname", StringType),
  StructField("favorite_color", IntegerType))
)).filter($"favorite_color" =!= "red").as('b) //dummy operations for example sake

df1.join(df2, $"a.name" === $"b.name")
```

Gives me the error:

```
cannot resolve '`b.name`' given input columns: [favorite_color, name, surname, age, surname, first_name];;
'Join Inner, (name#3 = 'b.name)
:- SubqueryAlias a
:  +- Filter NOT (name#3 = Sam)
:     +- LogicalRDD [name#3, surname#4, age#5]
+- SubqueryAlias b
   +- Filter NOT (cast(favorite_color#17 as double) = cast(red as double))
      +- LogicalRDD [first_name#15, surname#16, favorite_color#17]

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`b.name`' given input columns: [favorite_color, name, surname, age, surname, first_name];;
'Join Inner, (name#3 = 'b.name)
:- SubqueryAlias a
:  +- Filter NOT (name#3 = Sam)
:     +- LogicalRDD [name#3, surname#4, age#5]
+- SubqueryAlias b
   +- Filter NOT (cast(favorite_color#17 as double) = cast(red as double))
      +- LogicalRDD [first_name#15, surname#16, favorite_color#17]
```

Imagine if there are 15 different operations made to that dataframe, this will look super verbose! I want to mute/reduce this error message to just show the important bits. Like follows:

```
cannot resolve '`b.name`' given input columns: [favorite_color, name, surname, age, surname, first_name];;
'Join Inner, (name#3 = 'b.name)
```

Comment: do you want to mute all Errors, or just the history of operations?

Comment: i would like to mute the errors related to the actions of the dataframe - but not the immediate error itself. so the error should still show that the column is missing, but then stop there. cheers!